# Who killed Bronau?

Tags: tamora-pierce, tortall-universe

In Trickster's Choice, after Mequen is killed, I always thought that Dove was the one that killed Bronau with two arrows to the throat.

However, in the recap bit at the beginning of Trickster's Queen, it mentions that "Sarai refused to continue her lessons in swordcraft after she fought and beheaded her would-be lover, Prince Bronau, the night he slew her father" (page 2 of Trickster's Queen).

I know Sarai killed an assassin at one point, but I honestly thought it was Dove that killed Bronau.

Am I wrong? Which of the ladies killed Bronau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Dove. "Something thudded into Bronau. Aly couldn't see what it was.  He went still, wobbling on his feet.  Something else hit him.  Aly groped the man's neck until her swelling fingers hit two long, slender shafts buried in his throat... Aly looked across the bed.  Dove stood on the far side, a bow in her hand." This is from pg. 385 of *Trickster's Choice.*

Sarai tries to kill him, but he overpowers her, then attacks Aly and is on the verge of killing her when Dove intervenes.  Must be an editing error.  Nice catch.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't think he got beheaded. Hadn't read TC in a while, and can't find my copy, so it's nice to know I am right. :D

Comment: Great! Happy to help.